# Web browser behavior for relative path using CodeIgniter or any php framework

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, browser, relative-path

I've been using CodeIgniter for some time, but mostly for the convenience features such as internationalization, and cookie and session control. I also like that it separates my views from my logic. I have learned about the core things such as database access, which is the one of the core reasons why people use a php framework, but I just haven't been building sites that requires it for now.

One of the things that I couldn't find an answer on is about relative path. In my a tags, I've always put the complete path. For example

```
<a href="<?php echo '/' .$pageController . '/' . $pageMethod . '/' . $pageLanguage . '/home'; ?>">Home</a>
```

However, I've discovered that if I just put

```
<a href="home">Home</a>
```

it would actually work as long as I'm using the same controller, method and language. I even tried in the French section of my and it works too. Obviously, to switch language, I'd have to give the full path. I don't think this has anything to do with CI, but a browser behavior.

What is this behavior exactly? When a browser sees a relative path, does it look at the current path, goes to the nearest / character, erase everything after it and add the relative path? Can I count on this every time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can count on this behaviour. The approach of having slash-separated names to identify a page comes from the original approach of linking those strings to a folder location. So, `/users/halfer.html` would have been, prior to the popularity of dynamic routing, a file `halfer.html` inside a folder called `users`, which was itself inside the web/vhost root.

That means that, if you are in that page, any link that does not start with a protocol reference (e.g. `http://`) or a forward slash (i.e. the vhost root) is relative to the current address, so `BringMeAnother.html` would in fact reference `/users/BringMeAnother.html`.

Now, with modern routing, the `.html` suffix is redundant, so this can be dropped. However, the "folder-based" approach to relative links is still honoured by the browser. Thus, a link on this page to `BringMeAnother` would link to the route `/users/BringMeAnother`.

---

In relation to your comment, the implementation of some routing systems is rather partial, in my opinion. They will always convert a URI path to a controller, method and parameters, but they don't all offer named routes so that route hard-wiring can be avoided. However, this is probably very simple to add to CodeIgniter (of course, check that it is not offered already - it may be!).

Here's an example. Let's say your route `/users/:user_name` points to controller `UserController` and method `run`, and you wire each use case of this link in manually. You then decide that you wish to rename the route to `/browse/users/:user_name`, which is a problem since you've hardwired it in twenty places.

The solution is to add routes via a method that allows you to name them. Symfony 1 does this via this syntax:

```
@users?user_name=halfer
```

That means that a route named "users" would be expanded out to whatever the route definition was (e.g. `/browse/users/halfer`). However, I'm not suggesting you switch frameworks. Just add a custom method that stores names against route definitions (and adds them to your routing system automatically) so that you avoid hardwiring what a route looks like in each use case.

Comment: Thanks. I did discover one problem though. Using default routings, my home page would have something like www.mysite.com/ instead of being www.mysite.com/controller/method/language/page which means that local links would be www.mysite.com/otherpage which is broken instead of www.mysite.com/controller/method/language/otherpage. Time to make a welcome page and redirect. Is there a better solution?

Comment: @BringMeAnother: I've updated the post. I don't know CI so can't offer much help with implementation, but that's how I'd do it.